# C++ Цикл while...do работает на англ не работает на рус

Tags: c++, while

Почему такая программа выполняется корректно:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    setlocale (0, "");
    string first_name;
    string answer;

    do {
        cout << "Are you Ivan?\n";
        cin >> answer;
    }   while (answer != "no");

    cout << "Please type your name and press enter:\n";
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << "Well hello, " << first_name << " :)\n";
}
```

А такая в упор не реагирует на ответ "нет":

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    setlocale (0, "");
    string first_name;
    string answer;

    do {
        cout << "Ты Иван?\n";
        cin >> answer;
    }   while (answer != "нет");

    cout << "Введи своё имя и нажми enter:\n";
    cin >> first_name;
    cout << "Ну здорово, " << first_name << " :)\n";
}
```

Comment: т.е. ты вводишь с консоли слово "нет!" да?

Comment: В IDE запускаешь?

Comment: Потому что кодировки это очень весело, мб так что исходный файл у вас в одной кодировке, поэтому его `"нет"` будет в кодировке файла, а в консоли при вводе `"нет"` это будет в другой кодировке, поэтому распространение юникода (utf-8, utf-16, utf-x) это хорошо :)

Comment: у тебя написано setlocale(0, ""); это для вывода русских букв но ведь когда ты вводишь нет то он понимает вместо русских букв какие-то крякозябры.

Comment: В консоль ввожу "нет". Запускаю в Code Blocks.

Comment: проверь кодировку в консоли. Выше уже написали, по какой причине так происходит.

Answer (score 1):

`setlocale()` это такая коварная функция, которая меняет кодировку вывода, но с вводом все слегка сложнее... Можешь для примера просто вывести переменную с тем что ты вводишь, и сам увидишь что оно на самом деле считывает.

Попробуй использовать вместо этого `system("chcp 1251 & cls")` (изменение кодировки консоли на *Windows 1251*), не на всех ОС оно работает, но в основном да

Comment: Выводит: -?в    . А с system("chcp 1251 & cls") компилируется, но вообще даже предложение не выводит.

Comment: @RainInMyMind Если вопрос еще актуален: можно еще попробовать подключить библиотеку `<Windows.h>` и вместо `setlocale()` написать - `SetConsoleCP(1251)` для ввода и `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)` для вывода